# Perl regex can't find match

Tags: regex, bash, perl

So I'm working on my own little formatting correction script that uses Perl regex for substitution, but I can't get this one to match. I've used similar matching for other fixes but this one doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```bash
# basically takes in a string to modify and the match and substitution strings
perlRegex(){
  PERL_BADLANG=0 perl -le '
  $string = '"'"''"${1}"''"'"';
  $string =~ s/'"${2}"'/'"${3}"'/gm;
  print "$string\n";
  exit';
}

LINE_BREAK='\n'

# contents is the example below
EDITED=$(cat file.txt);
EDITED=$(perlRegex "${EDITED}" '(?<='"${LINE_BREAK}"')( +)([^{]+{$'"${LINE_BREAK}"')([^\s][^;]+;$)' '$1$2$1$1$3')
```

My current attempt is https://regex101.com/r/vgatOd/1 which gives me the output I want.

`(?<=\n)( +)([^{]+{$\n)([^\s][^;]+;$)`
to
`$1$2$1$1$3`

`(?<=\n)( +)` $1: copies the spaces at the beginning of the line

`([^{]+{$\n)` $2: captures the remaining content of the line with ending {

`([^\s][^;]+;$)` $3: captures the next line without a leading spaces, with ending ;

The substitution will add the spaces twice on before the second line.

Example input:

```
    if (debug) {
Tools.DebugLine("Log");
    }
```

Aim is to pad the Tools line to be at the correct column:

```
    if (debug) {
        Tools.DebugLine("Log");
    }
```

**Given the regex101 does what I would like it to do, I'm perplexed as to what part of it does not work in Perl regex.**

Comment: To match across multiple lines, you need to slurp the file, `perl -0777 -le`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've already managed to do that previously with my current setup, and even with that added it didn't find the match

Comment: It would be more efficient to provide a sample of input and expected output. Currently stated question does not make much sense. It is not obvious why Perl script in wrapped perhaps into shell script. Why not use Perl processing power to solve the problem on it's own.

Comment: @PolarBear added the wanted result. It is a shell script, originally was done by using `sed`, but then I moved to Perl given it's better support of different regex syntaxes

Comment: You could pad the line with leading space symbols like `$line =~ s/^ +/$space_pad/ if /Tools.DebugLine("Log");/`. But perhaps you want do this operation on many lines. Without seeing content of `file.txt` we are at guessing game about it's content. Upload the file somewhere and provide a link to it, after that at least it will be obvious what it looks like and what can be done to manipulate it's content to desired form. Perhaps you could do it in `vim` editor with a press of a few keyboard keys even without touching Perl.

Comment: As of this moment the problem is poorly described. Perhaps [vim](https://www.vim.org/) editor could solve your problem in a [few keystrokes](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_indentation). Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PolarBear the input is going to be .java files which don't follow our company's formatting guide lines. But to test this I've used a file which contains only the text given in the example which does not get formatted to be like in the regex101 link.

Answer (score 1):

Taken approach to make java file formatting isn't error prone, you should consider a better way to achieve the desired effect.

The chosen regular expression is quite excessive and mixes `\n`,  , `\s` all of which falls under `\s` class.

The following demo code strips regular expression for simplification.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $re = qr/([^\n]+?\{\s+)(\S+?;)(\s+\})/;
my $indent = ' ' x 8;

$data =~ s/$re/$1${indent}$2$3/gsm;

print $data;

__DATA__
    if (debug) {
Tools.DebugLine("Log");
    }
```

Output

```
    if (debug) {
        Tools.DebugLine("Log");
    }
```

Please see [Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score -2):

Solved by changing to just using `\n` instead of `$` along with them

https://regex101.com/r/poQlwm/1

`(?<=\n)([ ]+)([^{]+\{\n)([^\s][^;]+;\n)`